# Go get doesn't work, I have git

Tags: git, go, github-for-windows

Following go getting started page, want to install revel, it says it can't find hg, I have git and I am comfortable with it. Double checked %PATH%, it has Git/cmd and Git/bin

[image: Go get not working]

Comment: The error is very precise: `missing Mercurial command`, and `"hg": executable file not found in %PATH%`. Install mercurial (hg).

Comment: It's not telling you to use hg for your own stuff; the project you're importing uses hg, and `go get` wants to check it out, so you need to have `hg` installed for that.

Comment: whoa, that was something for my first day adventure with go

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> package revel
>
> import "github.com/revel/revel"
>
> [Packages imported by revel](http://godoc.org/github.com/revel/revel?imports)

The `go get` command installs a package and any missing import dependencies. The revel package imports "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket" from a Mercurial repository.

Install Mercurial (hg): [Mercurial Download](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download).